# Add HyperLink With Word JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office365, office-js

I'm having difficulties to add an HyperLink to my Word Document using the Javascript API. I've look to [Doc](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range?product=word) and I can't find any hints how to accomplish my duty...

**Here is my Question: *What is the best way to add an HyperLink inside a Word Document using the Javascript API.***

**And Here is what I tried:**

```
Word.run((context: Word.RequestContext) => {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    context.load(range, "hyperlink");
    return context.sync().then(() => {
        range.font.highlightColor = '#FFFF00';
        range.hyperlink = "C:\My Documents\MyFile.doc";
    }).then(context.sync);
});
```

I've added the highlightColor just to have a visual that my changes are being sync. Everything seems fine but the Hyperlink property is not being updated. Am I missing something?

And If you guys are wondering what's this syntax, I'm using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, if you don't mind i will reply in JavaScript :)

Setting a hyperlink to a file must work (provided that the file exists :) ). I have this simplified example working successfully, btw you don't need to load the range for setting this.

Also hyperlinks is now supported as **preview**, so please make sure that you are running an updated (latest) version of Word (go file and install updates)  and most importantly make sure you are using the preview CDN for Office.js which is here: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

```js
Word.run(function(context) {
        // Insert your code here. For example:
       context.document.getSelection().hyperlink = "C:\My Documents\MyFile.doc";
        
        return context.sync();
    });
```

Comment: Can you tell me your word version?
Hyperlink dont work for me...
I'm on version 1610 (Build 7416.1000) (Office Insider Fast)

Comment: Thanks "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" fix the issue